# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is tracked

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

When trying to remove `PendingUser` from database, I get an error:

> 'The instance of entity type 'PendingUser' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the key value '{UserId: 123}' is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached.'

```
  public async Task RemoveAsync(PendingUser pendingUser)
  {
     _context.PendingUsers.Remove(pendingUser);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does your `_context` was injected as `scoped`?

Comment: If `pendingUser` is an input (like DTO) and was not recovered from the context (with tracking), you need to `attach` before `remove`.

Comment: Find out what was your `DbContext` doing before this operation, and how did it get a `PendingUser` entity with `UserId` value `123`. We really can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, DBContext is injected as `scoped`.This practice helps to maintain the tracking as clean as possible.

However, it can be a simple tracking problem.

If `pendingUser` is an input (like DTO) and was not recovered from the context (with tracking), you need to attach it before removing it.

Bellow, some suggestions as you can use as the removal behaviors:

```cs
public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : Entity<TId>
    where TId : struct
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    protected Repository(DbContext dbDbContext)
    {
        _dbSet = dbDbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TId id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id, asTracking: true);
        if (entity is null) return;
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity is null) return;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(TId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = await GetByIdAsync(id, cancellationToken, asTracking: true);
        if (entity is null) return;
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (entity is null) return;
        await Task.Run(() => Delete(entity), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Full sample [here](https://github.com/AntonioFalcao/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.WebApplication/blob/release/src/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.Repositories.Abstractions/Repository.cs).
Also can check the dependency injection strategy [here](https://github.com/AntonioFalcao/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.WebApplication/blob/release/src/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.Store.Repositories/Extensions/DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

In this particular case, the `SaveChanges` and other `DBContext` behaviors were encapsulated by the `UnitOfWork`. That provides transaction control by the Service layer.

```cs
public abstract class Service<TEntity, TModel, TId> : IService<TEntity, TModel, TId>
    where TEntity : Entity<TId> 
    where TModel : Model<TId> 
    where TId : struct
{
    protected readonly IMapper Mapper;
    protected readonly IRepository<TEntity, TId> Repository;
    protected readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    protected Service(IRepository<TEntity, TId> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        Repository = repository;
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        Mapper = mapper;
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(TId id)
    {
        if (IsValid(id) is false) return default;
        Repository.Delete(id);
        return UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(TModel model)
    {
        if (IsValid(model) is false) return default;
        var entity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
        return OnDelete(entity);
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsValid(id) is false) return default;
        await Repository.DeleteAsync(id, cancellationToken);
        return await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    
    public virtual async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsValid(model) is false) return default;
        var entity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
        return await OnDeleteAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

[Service abstractions](https://github.com/AntonioFalcao/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.WebApplication/blob/release/src/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.Services.Abstractions/Service.cs)
[UnitOfWork](https://github.com/AntonioFalcao/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.WebApplication/blob/release/src/Dotnet5.GraphQL3.Repositories.Abstractions/UnitsOfWork/UnitOfWork.cs)

Comment: @Taifunov, have you checked the solution?